# embedded url at target

Tags: javascript, html

This is normally a simple solution if I were using `<a href>` but  because I am using `<input>` I can't figure out how to make this open a new window using `target="_blank"`. Is there any way to do this that combines the onclick and all in this one line of code?

```html
 <INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="SURVEY" Onclick="window.location.href='HTTP://WWW.YAHOO.COM'">
```

Comment: If you want a link. Use a link. There is no good reason to involve JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) instead

```html
<INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="SURVEY" Onclick="window.open('HTTP://WWW.YAHOO.COM');">
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: here it will not work because Stack Snippets are sandboxes. try it in a custom page